# Python ElementTree - print out namespace definitions?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using Python's elementtree to parse some XML configuration files.

At the top of the file, I have a root element like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sgx:FooConfig
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:foo="http://ns.au.firm.com/foo.xsd"
  xmlns:bar="http://ns.au.firm.com/bar.xsd"
  >
```

The problem is, the `bar` namespace can be set to one of two different XSDs, depending on the version of the configuration file.

I'm looking for a way to print out the namespace mapping using ElementTree, so I can check which of the two XSDs is being used - then I can get my code to handle the correct case.

Is there a way to print out all the namespace definitions out using Python?

Cheers,
Victor

Comment: Wouldn't it be smarter to search the document for the *occurance* of nodes in either namespace, and change processing depending on which is found?

Comment: Also, your root element appears to be invalid. Where is the namespace declaration for the `sgx` prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is not valid xml (undefined prefixes) and I think you can't do this with `xml.etree` but you should be able to do it using `lxml`.

```
import lxml.etree as et
tree = et.XML(yourxml)
print tree.nsmap
```